# Can't authorise android lenovo tablet in USB debugging mode

Tags: applications, usb-debugging, lenovo

I have **Lenovo YOGA Tablet 2** **830LC** *X86*.

`Rescue and Smart Assistant tool` is a software to work with this tablet.
When i activate USB-Debugging in tablet i face the error below in `Rescue and Smart Assistant tool`.

[image: Unauthorized]

Unauthorized is because after activating USB-Debugging mode in tablet and connecting my tablet to PC, there is no popup asking me if i want to trust this PC, which i have to agree (permanently).

By deleting the adbkey file found in `C:\Users\[Username]\.android` folder the permission dialog did n't appear on my device.

What should i do to fix this issue?

---

Edit after comment :

1. I am using USB charging cable.
2. I have windows 7
3. USB OEM driver for Lenovo > When i connect
   lenovo tablet to pc a pop up shows up on pc to install usb driver.
   So i installed it & after that i can see tablet folders.
   But i did n't install any other things.
4. Have you reset the USB authorization on
   the device too (usually inside Developer options) > Is this your
   mean `revoke USB debugging authorization`? If yes i did it several times.
5. Is the device detected by ADB (call adb devices on command prompt)
   I found a `adb.exe` in this path : `C:\MagicPlusMini\app`
   After enter `adb devices` command it founds : `Baytrail6F284E37 offline`
   I found another `adb.exe`
   Here is the command prompt :
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Rescue and Smart Assistant>adb devices`
   `List of devices attached adb server is out of date. killing...`
   `daemon started successfully`
   `Baytrail6F284E37 unauthorized`

Comment: I would delete all those old adb versions and use the one from Android SDK. Multiple adb versions in one computer only make problems or replace those versions with the one from Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolution**
Possible solutions if `adb devices` shows a device as `unauthorized`:

> C:\Users\JohnDoo>adb devices
> List of devices attached
> 17310D821D  > unauthorized

1. Disconnect USB between PC and device
2. Stop adb server by entering `adb kill-server` in command window
3. On device use `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` in `Developer Options`
4. On PC delete `adbkey` file in user directory, for example `C:\Users\JohnDoo\.android`
5. Reconnect the device to the PC
6. Open a command window and enter `adb devices`. Watch the device's screen for any Authorization message and allow the connection.

The device should now show as `device`:

> C:\Users\JohnDoo>adb devices
> List of devices attached
> 17310D821D  > device

If the above does not help, re-installing adb and or USB drivers may help.